# Filtering PHI data when logging with bunyan (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, bunyan

When logging an object (JSON object with many data elements), how can we filter PHI data and not log them

e.g SSN, Creditcard etc

Are there any available solutions which filter this, or allow to configure such filters.